# what wrong with word architect?

Tags: grammaticality

> That's because my grandfather was a traditional Balinese building architect all the buildings in my house were designed by him.

Can anyone answer what wrong with word architect? What wrong with grammar?

Comment: You tell us what you think is wrong with it.

Comment: Nothing that a bit of punctuation wouldn't fix.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the word _architect_, but it's unnecessary to add _building_ because an architect is by definition a designer of buildings..

Comment: Should "all the buildings in my house" be "all the buildings on my property"?

Answer (score 1):

> That's because my grandfather was a traditional Balinese building architect all the buildings in my house were designed by him.

What's wrong with it:

1. Is the word 'building' connected to the word 'Balinese' or the word 'architect'? Are you saying your grandfather was a 'building architect' or an architect of 'Balinese buildings'?
2. What is 'traditional' related to? Was your grandfather a traditional architect, or did he design traditional buildings?
3. You appear to have two clauses but no punctuation.
4. You appear to have buildings inside your house?

I think it should be:

> That's because my grandfather was a traditional Balinese architect. All the buildings around my house were designed by him.